# Llama index- training my own model gives poor results

Tags: openai-api, training-data, large-language-model, llama

I'm trying to learn how to utilise LLM's power and train my own datasets.
I've been writing this simple script which is fully functional and working, but gives very poor results.

I.e- When I ask it quite simple questions on the dataset below it's often not accurate. (questions about number of layoff, industry, etc).

Does this relate mainly to indexing and embedding of the data?

I provide the dataset example, and the script extract below.

| Company | Total Layoffs | Impacted Workforce Percentage | Reported Date | Industry | Headquarter Location | Sources | Status | Additional Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C2FO | 20 | 2 | 12/9/2022 | Fintech, payments | Leawood, KS | Kansas City Business Journal | Private | No additional notes |
| VideoAmp | Unclear | 2 | 9/19/2022 | Advertising platforms | Los Angeles | Company memo | Private | No additional notes |

```
def createOrLoadIndex(path):
    # If index doesn't exist, create it and save.
    # Path is the location of the CSV file
    if not(Path('naval_index').is_dir()):
        print("Creating index")
        PagedCSVReader = download_loader("PagedCSVReader")

        loader = PagedCSVReader(encoding="utf-8")
        documents = loader.load_data(file=Path(path))


        # embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding()
        # service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(embed_model=embed_model)
        # prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
        #     context_window=4096,
        #     num_output=256,
        #     chunk_overlap_ratio=0.1,
        #     chunk_size_limit=None
        # )
        index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
            documents=documents
            # , prompt_helper=prompt_helper
            # ,service_context=service_context
        )
        # index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(documents)
        index.storage_context.persist("naval_index")


    # Load index, and return a query engine
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="naval_index")
    index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)

    return (index.as_chat_engine())
    # return index
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and got very inaccurate results using my own dataset

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).